# zmq REQ packets sent only after dll exit

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, zeromq

I got a program that create zmq REQ socket and send some data, from some reason the data sent only after the `DllMain` (after msgbox 4) and not right after `zmq_send()`.

```
void  client_init(void *z_socket) {
    assert(z_socket == NULL);

    void *context = NULL;
    zmq_msg_t send_msg;
    zmq_msg_init_data(&send_msg, "asdf", 4, NULL, NULL);

    context = zmq_init(10);
    MessageBox(NULL, "msg1", "yes", 1);
    z_socket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    assert(z_socket != NULL);

    MessageBox(NULL, "msg2", "yes", 1);
    assert(zmq_connect(z_socket, "tcp://127.0.0.1:3490") != -1);
    zmq_send(z_socket, &send_msg2, 0);


    MessageBox(NULL, "msg3", "yes", 1);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(...) {
    void *z_socket = NULL;
    client_init(z_socket);
    MessageBox(NULL, "msg4", "yes", 1);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Why does it happen???

btw im using pyzmq as a server that listen at port 3490

Comment: I'm not sure if it is related to the issue you are seeing but you appear to be mising a `;` at the end of the `client_init(z_socket)` line. This should be a compile error.

Comment: Strange things can happen in `DllMain`... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx Try to move out your code outside of `DllMain`

Comment: @JosephH You're right! Very strange things happen in DllMain... I tried to run the same code from another thread (that I opened from DllMain and the packet sent write after zmq_send). Thank you for your comment